# How to hide the keyboard while presenting another viewcontroller on textFieldDidBeginEditing delegate in swift?

Tags: swift, keyboard

I have two text fields one for file name and another for choosing the options from the another view controller. I am using second text field as dropdown. The problem is that when I click on first text field and then clicking on second textfield then keyboard is not getting hide.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == "fileUserCan" {
        textField.endEditing(true)
        guard  let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "DownloadView", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DonwloadViewVC") as? ViewDownloadViewController else {return}
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        controller.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve

        controller.callback = { check in
            self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
            if check == 1 {
                textField.text = "download"
            } else {
                textField.text = "file"
            }
        }
        textField.endEditing(true)
        self.present(controller , animated: true)

    }
}
```

Comment: use textfield.resignFirstResponder()

Comment: not working only working if Im only tapping on second text field

Comment: you also have it in combination with textFieldDidEndEditing?

Comment: can you plz specify with code

Answer (score 0):

U can specify a tag for the first textfield.

If you done this you can do something like this:

```
 func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.tag == 1 {
       textfield.resignFirstResponder()
    }
 }
```

Comment: not working keyboard is still opened when I am coming from first textfield

Comment: Try the code above with the second textfield. I believe that the first keyboard is already closed, but as soon as you press on the second textfield, a new keyboard is called directly.